# Determine the sets $cl(B^2), int(B^2), ext(B^2)$ and $\partial B^2$ in the topology of $\Bbb R^2$ that's induced by $\pi_1: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$.

Tags: general-topology

> Determine the sets $cl(B^2), int(B^2), ext(B^2)$ and $\partial B^2$ in the topology of $\Bbb R^2$ that's induced by the projection $\pi_1: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$.

So I need to look at the preimages of the open sets of $\Bbb R^2$ to see how the induced topology behaves? I have that $\pi_1^{-1}(a,b) = \{x \in \Bbb R^2 : \pi_1(x) \in (a,b) \}$ but isn't this just equal to $(a,b) \times \Bbb R^2$ since every point in the strip above the interval $(a,b)$ in $\Bbb R^2$, gets mapped to the open set $(a,b) \subset \Bbb R$?

Comment: Do you have some typos? Do you mean $\pi_1:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$?

Comment: $\pi_1$ is from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ (not $\Bbb R^2$ again), $(a, b) \times\Bbb R^2$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^3$, while $\pi^{-1}((a,b)) \subset \Bbb R^2$. And $(a,b) \subset \Bbb R$, not $\Bbb R^2$. And what is $B$?